# Mapbox GL Loading Missing Raster Tiles Error Image

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on a GL project which is a conversion from Leaflet. Under Leaflet when we set a tile bounds (maxbounds limit of view) it was possible to render a default or error tile image when you are outside of the max bounds. So in may case I would render a tile which stated showed a message stating the selected data was only available for Australia (or whatever country/region).

In leaflet this is called:
errorTileUrl    String  ''  URL to the tile image to show in place of the tile that failed to load.

This meant  I did not have to have blank/msg image tiles loaded into the tile server. Is this at all possible with the MapBox GL system.

Here is the style I am using:

```
            style: {
            "version": 8,
            "sources": {
                "Tiles": {
                    "type": "raster",
                    "tiles": ["https://myprivate server/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"],
                    "tileSize": 256
                }
            },
            "layers": [{
                "id": "Tiles",
                "type": "raster",
                "source": "Tiles",
                "minzoom": 0,
                "maxzoom": 13
            }],
            "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/outdoors-v9",
            "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
        },
```

I still want to be able to view the world just send out a blank/default tile when there is a http download error with the requested tile. At the moment it renders a white square and gives a console error for the failed download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible in GL JS. We are tracking the implementation of TileJSON's `maxBounds` at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1775

Depending on your use case, you may be able to implement this feature downstream by adding features in response to the `tile.error` event or by adding a layer beneath your raster layer which displays your desired loading / errored texture.